# iFrame - Open Links inside iFrame in same window

Tags: iframe, window, parent

I got an iFrame which contains links. I want the links to open in same window - parrent window (not inside the iframe.)

`target="_parent"` only works when the URL is specified as http://www.example.com

I would like the links to open as `<a href="/register"> register </a>`

In other words, the /register parameter has to be added to the URL of parent page.

Will it be possible to do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

When the iFrame is on different server from the main page, seems like only JavaScript is the only option. Here is a script that I did:

```
<script>

       window.onload = function(){
        var url = document.referrer;
        document.getElementById('myLink').href=url+"/register";
                };
    </script>

<a target="_parent"  href="" id="myLink"> Click me </a>
```

This needs to be written in the document which will be turned into the iframe.

HTML tag target="_parent" would only work if the iFrame would be on the same server as the page. In my case it was:

iframe location - www.example.com
page location: www.test.com